MongoDb Node.js driver closing connection before it finishes request
I have created a function, that when called, it should make a findOne request to a database an return the result. However... (most of the time) it ends up throwing a "MongoTopologyClosedError: Topology is closed" or "PoolClosedError [MongoPoolClosedError]: Attempted to check out a connection from closed connection pool"
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb"
const client = new MongoClient(process.env.DB_URL);
export function getOne(db, collection, filter, projection = {}, errorOnNotFound = false) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let output, error;
    try {
      await client.connect();
      const mongoDB = client.db(db);
      const mongoCollection = mongoDB.collection(collection);

      output = await mongoCollection.findOne(filter, projection);
    }
    catch (err) {
      error = err;
    }
    finally {
      await client.close();
      if (error) {
        console.error("getOne error:\n  DB:", db, "\n  Collection:", collection, "\n  Filter:", filter, "\n  Error:", error);
        reject(new Error("Database Error"));
      }
      else {
        if (output) resolve(output);
        else if (errorOnNotFound) {
          reject(new Error("Not Found"));
        }
        else resolve(null);
      }
    }
  });
}

Interesting thing is... if i wrap everything in the "finally" block inside a timeout as to delay it, it works, so it seems to me, the mongodb driver simply doesn't properly await finishing the request to the database
From seraches om google, i understand that for the backend of a web aplication it is not necesary to close the connection, but i'd still like to understand why this doesn't work...
